# Protect against parallel transaction updating row

Tags: sql, database, database-design, transactions

I'm building a simple set of queries for an SQL database. I've come across a situation I want to protect against, but I don't know the database theory terminology to explain what I'm asking.

In this example I have two simultaneous transactions occurring on a database. Transaction #1 begins and Transaction #2 begins after T1 but T2 ends before T1 does its commit.

The table USERS has columns id, name, passwordHash

```
--Transaction #1
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT id from USERS where name = someName;
--do some work, transaction #2 starts and completes quickly while this work is being performed 
UPDATE USERS SET name = newName where id = $id;
COMMIT;

--Transaction #2
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT id from USERS where name = someName;
UPDATE USERS SET passwordHash = newPasswordHash where id = $id;
COMMIT;
```

I would like to have some kind of safety check performed where by if I am updating a row, I am only updating the same version of that row that existed at the time the transaction started.

In this case, I would like the Transaction 1 `COMMIT` to fail because Transaction 2 has already updated the row belonging to user with name `someName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SELECT FOR UPDATE with NOWAIT to lock the rows against concurrent modifications by other transactions. That will guarantee that your later updates will run against the same version of those rows; other transaction cannot change these rows until your transaction commits.

Example (using Postgresql):

Transaction 1:

```
begin transaction;
select * from users where username = 'Fabian' for update nowait;
update users set passwordHash = '123' where username = 'Fabian';
commit;
```

Transaction 2, somewhere after transaction 1 has selected for update, but not committed:

```
> select * from users where username = 'Fabian' for update nowait;
ERROR:  could not obtain lock on row in relation "users"
```

**Edit**

This is usually called pessimistic locking. The transaction that first selects the row will "win", any later select for update will fail. If you want that the transaction wins that first writes a change, you might want to go for an optimistic locking approach, as proposed by @Laurence.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to add a `rowversion` column to the table. You read this column along with the rest of the data. When you submit an update, you include it in the where clause. You can then check the number of rows affected to see if another transaction got in first.

Some databases have native support for such columns. E.g. SQL Server has the `timestamp/rowversion` datatype. Oracle has `rowdependencies`. DB2 has `rowversion`.